# Functional programming in Python: returning none instead of correct value

Tags: python, functional-programming

I wrote a functional code in python and I do not understand why it returns a None instead of the correct value which the code clearly generates.

The purpose of this script is to take a line.split(',') from a CSV and reassemble any values that were inadvertently split from '{value1,value2,value3}' into 'value1,value2 ... valueN'.

```
def reassemble(list_name):
    def inner_iter(head, tail):
        if head[0][0] == '{':
            new_head = [head[0] + ',' + tail[0]]
            if tail[0][-1] == '}':
                return [new_head[0][1:-1]], tail[1:]
            else:
                inner_iter(new_head, tail[1:])

    def outer_iter(corrected_list, head, tail):
        if tail == []:
            print corrected_list + head
            return corrected_list + head
        else:
            if head[0][0] == '{':
                head, tail = inner_iter(head, tail)
                outer_iter(corrected_list + head, [tail[0]], tail[1:])

            else:
                outer_iter(corrected_list + head, [tail[0]], tail[1:])

    return outer_iter([], [list_name[0]], list_name[1:])
```

Below is a test:

```
x = ['x','y', '{a', 'b}', 'c']
print reassemble(x)
```

And this is the odd result:

```
['x', 'y', 'a,b', 'c'] #from the print inside "outer_iter"
None                   #from the print reassemble(x)
```

Note: I want to keep the code functional as an exercise.

Comment: Without running the code, I could see a few potential problems. Your inner and outer_iter functions do not return a value always

Comment: How was this question "too localized"? I can understand that my attempt to separate this post from how Python's interpretation of functional programming works may have been misconstrued or potentially against Stackoverflow policy (and this is debatable), but this question is still very relevant - see comments on Elazar's post.

Comment: This question is definitely not "too localized".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot `return` in the `else` clause, at `outer_iter`.

In python, function that does not return specific value, returns `None`.

[EDIT]

full source:

```
def reassemble(list_name):
    def inner_iter(head, tail):
        if head[0][0] == '{':
            new_head = [head[0] + ',' + tail[0]]
            if tail[0][-1] == '}':
                return [new_head[0][1:-1]], tail[1:]
            else:
                return inner_iter(new_head, tail[1:])
                #before the change, control reached here upon return
        #control might still reach here, in case 'if' condition was not met
        #implicitly "return None"

    def outer_iter(corrected_list, head, tail):
        if tail == []:
            print corrected_list + head
            return corrected_list + head
        else:
            if head[0][0] == '{':
                head, tail = inner_iter(head, tail)
                return outer_iter(corrected_list + head, [tail[0]], tail[1:])
                #before the change, control reached here upon return
            else:
                return outer_iter(corrected_list + head, [tail[0]], tail[1:])
                #before the change, control reached here upon return
        #before the change, control reached here upon return
        #implicitly "return None"

    return outer_iter([], [list_name[0]], list_name[1:])
```

test:

```
x = ['x','y', '{a', 'b}', 'c']
print reassemble(x)
```

output:

```
['x', 'y', 'a,b', 'c']
['x', 'y', 'a,b', 'c']
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why the "return" is required if the functions always converges to the tail == []. And if a "return" is required to make the function recurring, why does Python still print the correct value in the first case? Ps: Thank you

Comment: I think I know where your problem came from: you are used to functional languages, such as ML, Haskell, etc. In such languages you do not write any `return` statements. Well, Python is _not_ a functional language, it just supports functional programming.

Comment: (the first comment was not an answer to your comment)
the code converges, but you will see what happens here if you will put `return None` at the end of the function, and follow the usual imperative control flow.

Comment: I see. So effectively, Python has to pass the return values back through every iteration, and this is why the return statements are required?

Comment: Yes. that's exactly what happens anyway, except that in ML you will not write `return` - as function body is an expression. In python, function body is a compound statement. python's `lambda`s are more like what you are used to.

Comment: python is an imperative language. statements are executed sequentially, unless an explicit control-flow construct is encountered. in functions, there are two ways to return: `return` statement, or falling-through-the-end. Fallthrough and simple `return`s behaves in a way that resembles C - that is, the "unit" (C's void, Python's NoneType) is returned.

Answer (score 1):

```
def reassemble(list_name):
    def inner_iter(head, tail):
        if head[0][0] == '{':
            new_head = [head[0] + ',' + tail[0]]
            if tail[0][-1] == '}':
                return [new_head[0][1:-1]], tail[1:]
            else:
                return inner_iter(new_head, tail[1:])

    def outer_iter(corrected_list, head, tail):
        if tail == []:
            print corrected_list + head
            return corrected_list + head
        else:
            if head[0][0] == '{':
                head, tail = inner_iter(head, tail)
                return outer_iter(corrected_list + head, [tail[0]], tail[1:])

            else:
                return outer_iter(corrected_list + head, [tail[0]], tail[1:])

    return outer_iter([], [list_name[0]], list_name[1:])



x = ['x','y', '{a', 'b}', 'c']

print reassemble(x)
```

See the running code in this Bunk http://codebunk.com/bunk#-It06-ImaZDpSrCrQSmM